# Calculating elapsed time

Tags: sql, datetime, formatting, informix

The code below compares recv.rcpt_dtim (which is a datetime type) against the current date/time. It calculates an elapsed time resulting in hours and minutes formatted like: "04:22". It took me a while to get it functional, which it is, but it just seems sloppy. Does anyone have any tips to clean it up?

```
TRIM((((CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) to 
SECOND)/3600)::VARCHAR(12) || ':' || CASE WHEN (MOD(MOD(((CURRENT YEAR TO 
MINUTE - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL MINUTE(9) to 
MINUTE)::VARCHAR(12)::INT,60),60))<10 THEN "0" ELSE "" END || 
(MOD(MOD(((CURRENT YEAR TO MINUTE - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL MINUTE(9) 
to MINUTE)::VARCHAR(12)::INT,60),60))::VARCHAR(12))
```

Comment: Question asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064149/how-to-clean-up-sql-expression) too.  Essentially the same answer, but less verbose, was given on SO by A.N.Other user than me.

Answer (score 4):

When I use your complex expression, I don't get the leading zeros on the hour field that your code suggests that you want.  AFAICS, the expression that tries to add a leading zero is fiddling with the minutes field.  I'm not sure why you're doing the double MOD operations, either.

I think it is sufficient to use the vastly simpler `CAST` expression shown in the following SELECT statement.  Here, instead of using `CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND` (or minor variants thereupon), I've created a second table, `reference_times`, with a single column `reftime` of type `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND`.  That allows me to test many different reference times reliably, in a way that using CURRENT simple does not.  I use an explicit CROSS JOIN between the reference times and the `recv` table to compare every row in each table with each of the rows in the other.

```
SELECT reft.reftime,
       recv.rcpt_dtim,
       (reft.reftime - recv.rcpt_dtim) AS delta_t_1,
       CAST(reft.reftime - recv.rcpt_dtim AS INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO MINUTE) AS delta_t_2,
       TRIM((((reft.reftime - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND)/3600)::VARCHAR(12) ||
           ':' ||
           CASE WHEN (MOD(MOD(((reft.reftime - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL MINUTE(9) TO MINUTE)::VARCHAR(12)::INT,60),60))<10
           THEN "0"
           ELSE "" END || 
           (MOD(MOD(((reft.reftime - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL MINUTE(9) TO MINUTE)::VARCHAR(12)::INT,60),60))::VARCHAR(12)) AS delta_t_3
  FROM reference_times AS reft JOIN recv ON 1 = 1
 ORDER BY reft.reftime, recv.rcpt_dtim;
```

Given the setup code:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE reference_times
(
    reftime     DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO reference_times VALUES('2019-05-01 03:01:03');
INSERT INTO reference_times VALUES('2019-05-01 05:32:27');
INSERT INTO reference_times VALUES('2019-05-01 10:22:44');
INSERT INTO reference_times VALUES('2019-05-01 12:49:00');
INSERT INTO reference_times VALUES('2019-05-01 14:59:59');
INSERT INTO reference_times VALUES('2019-05-01 23:59:58');

CREATE TEMP TABLE recv
(
    rcpt_dtim   DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-05-01 01:10:11');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-05-01 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-30 22:19:45');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-30 18:37:21');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-30 03:31:00');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-30 01:19:45');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-30 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-29 20:10:58');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-10 22:09:00');
INSERT INTO recv VALUES('2019-04-01 22:09:00');
```

I get output such as:

```
reftime              rcpt_dtim               delta_t_1 delta_t_2  delta_t_3
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-01 22:09:00   29 04:52:03    700:52  700:52
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-10 22:09:00   20 04:52:03    484:52  484:52
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-29 20:10:58    1 06:50:05     30:50  30:50
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-30 00:00:00    1 03:01:03     27:01  27:01
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-30 01:19:45    1 01:41:18     25:41  25:41
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-30 03:31:00    0 23:30:03     23:30  23:30
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-30 18:37:21    0 08:23:42      8:23  8:23
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-04-30 22:19:45    0 04:41:18      4:41  4:41
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-05-01 01:10:11    0 01:50:52      1:50  1:50
2019-05-01 03:01:03  2019-05-01 02:00:00    0 01:01:03      1:01  1:01
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-01 22:09:00   29 07:23:27    703:23  703:23
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-10 22:09:00   20 07:23:27    487:23  487:23
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-29 20:10:58    1 09:21:29     33:21  33:21
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-30 00:00:00    1 05:32:27     29:32  29:32
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-30 01:19:45    1 04:12:42     28:12  28:12
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-30 03:31:00    1 02:01:27     26:01  26:01
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-30 18:37:21    0 10:55:06     10:55  10:55
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-04-30 22:19:45    0 07:12:42      7:12  7:12
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-05-01 01:10:11    0 04:22:16      4:22  4:22
2019-05-01 05:32:27  2019-05-01 02:00:00    0 03:32:27      3:32  3:32
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-01 22:09:00   29 12:13:44    708:13  708:13
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-10 22:09:00   20 12:13:44    492:13  492:13
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-29 20:10:58    1 14:11:46     38:11  38:11
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-30 00:00:00    1 10:22:44     34:22  34:22
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-30 01:19:45    1 09:02:59     33:02  33:02
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-30 03:31:00    1 06:51:44     30:51  30:51
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-30 18:37:21    0 15:45:23     15:45  15:45
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-04-30 22:19:45    0 12:02:59     12:02  12:02
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-05-01 01:10:11    0 09:12:33      9:12  9:12
2019-05-01 10:22:44  2019-05-01 02:00:00    0 08:22:44      8:22  8:22
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-01 22:09:00   29 14:40:00    710:40  710:40
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-10 22:09:00   20 14:40:00    494:40  494:40
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-29 20:10:58    1 16:38:02     40:38  40:38
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-30 00:00:00    1 12:49:00     36:49  36:49
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-30 01:19:45    1 11:29:15     35:29  35:29
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-30 03:31:00    1 09:18:00     33:18  33:18
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-30 18:37:21    0 18:11:39     18:11  18:11
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-04-30 22:19:45    0 14:29:15     14:29  14:29
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-05-01 01:10:11    0 11:38:49     11:38  11:38
2019-05-01 12:49:00  2019-05-01 02:00:00    0 10:49:00     10:49  10:49
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-01 22:09:00   29 16:50:59    712:50  712:50
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-10 22:09:00   20 16:50:59    496:50  496:50
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-29 20:10:58    1 18:49:01     42:49  42:49
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-30 00:00:00    1 14:59:59     38:59  38:59
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-30 01:19:45    1 13:40:14     37:40  37:40
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-30 03:31:00    1 11:28:59     35:28  35:28
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-30 18:37:21    0 20:22:38     20:22  20:22
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-04-30 22:19:45    0 16:40:14     16:40  16:40
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-05-01 01:10:11    0 13:49:48     13:49  13:49
2019-05-01 14:59:59  2019-05-01 02:00:00    0 12:59:59     12:59  12:59
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-01 22:09:00   30 01:50:58    721:50  721:50
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-10 22:09:00   21 01:50:58    505:50  505:50
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-29 20:10:58    2 03:49:00     51:49  51:49
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-30 00:00:00    1 23:59:58     47:59  47:59
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-30 01:19:45    1 22:40:13     46:40  46:40
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-30 03:31:00    1 20:28:58     44:28  44:28
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-30 18:37:21    1 05:22:37     29:22  29:22
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-04-30 22:19:45    1 01:40:13     25:40  25:40
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-05-01 01:10:11    0 22:49:47     22:49  22:49
2019-05-01 23:59:58  2019-05-01 02:00:00    0 21:59:58     21:59  21:59
```

Column names/types:

```
reftime      DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
rcpt_dtim    DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
delta_t_1    INTERVAL DAY(8) TO SECOND
delta_t_2    INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO MINUTE
delta_t_3    VARCHAR(26)
```

Observe that the `delta_t_2` column produces the same output as the `delta_t_3` column — apart from type (interval vs string); the left vs right adjustment is mostly an artefact of the way the program that generated the data futzes with the formatting.

Consequently, your elaborate expression can be simplified to:

```
CAST(CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND - recv.rcpt_dtim AS INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO MINUTE)
```

or:

```
(CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND - recv.rcpt_dtim)::INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO MINUTE
```

And if your time gaps are small enough, you can change the `4` to `2`.